# N-ary trees in numba

Tags: python, numba

I need to implement a tree structure where each node has an arbitrary number of children. This seems to be straightforward when the number of children is known (linked list, binary tree, etc.), but I have not managed to implement it in the more general case.

For instance, I have tried to extend this [linked list example](https://github.com/numba/numba/blob/master/examples/linkedlist.py) by changing the `next` parameter into a list. However, it seems one cannot have a list of `deferred_type`. Any ideas on how to implement this?

```
from collections import OrderedDict 
from numba import njit, jitclass, types, int32, deferred_type, optional
import numpy as np 

node_type = deferred_type()

spec = OrderedDict() 
spec['data'] = int32 
spec['next'] = optional(types.ListType(node_type))


@jitclass(spec) 
class LinkedNode:
    def __init__(self, data, next):
        self.data = data
        self.next = next

    def prepend(self, data):
        return LinkedNode(data, self)


@njit def make_linked_node(data):
    return LinkedNode(data, None)


node_type.define(LinkedNode.class_type.instance_type)
```

Answer (score 0):

I found an alternative that, while not being exactly what I wanted, still gets the job done. It is basically a standard extension of a binary tree that includes more nodes in-between the left and right ones (see [this article](https://www.cs.cmu.edu/~pattis/15-1XX/15-200/lectures/specialtrees/index.html)).

These structures usually only keep track of the first (left) child, but I also have a pointer to the last (right) one, as it facilitates arranging all edges using only the parent node.

```
from collections import OrderedDict
from numba import jitclass, int64, deferred_type, optional

node_type = deferred_type()

spec = OrderedDict()
spec['id'] = int64
spec['parent'] = optional(node_type)
spec['left_child'] = optional(node_type)  # first child
spec['right_child'] = optional(node_type) # last child
spec['sibling'] = optional(node_type)  # next sibling


@jitclass(spec)
class Node:
    def __init__(self, id, parent):
        self.id = id
        self.parent = parent
        # initialize parent and left right children as None
        self.left_child = None
        self.right_child = None
        self.sibling = None
        if parent is not None:
            parent.add_child(self)

    @property
    def children(self):
    """ A list with all children. """
        children = []
        child = self.left_child
        while child is not None:
            children.append(child)
            child = child.sibling
        return children

    def add_sibling(self, sibling):
        self.sibling = sibling

    def add_child(self, child):
        # if parent has no children
        if self.left_child is None:
            # this node is it first child
            self.left_child = child
            self.right_child = child
        else:
            # the last (now right) child will have this node as sibling
            self.right_child.add_sibling(child)
            self.right_child = child


node_type.define(Node.class_type.instance_type)
```